# Select all divs except divs inside one class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I select all `divs` inside a `div` except `divs` which are nested inside one `class`?

For example:

```css
#test div :not(.testAgain) div {
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">  
  <div>
    Some Content
  </div>
  <div>
    Some Content
    <div class="testAgain">
      <div>Some Content again</div>...<div>Test Content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I select all `div`s inside the `#test` div except the `div`s that are inside  the `.testAgain` div, i.e. any CSS that I apply should apply to all `div`s except the content inside the `.testAgain` div.

I've tried:

```css
#test div :not(.testAgain) div{
  /* some CSS Styling */
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. (no jQuery please!)

*EDIT:* There are actually dozens of nested `div`s ... and the `.testAgain` div is somewhat 6-7 levels deep down the main (`#test`) div.

Comment: Your real issue is that there's no parent selector in CSS, so you can't say "don't select this div if it's inside this other div with a certain class", all you can do is as the answers are suggesting, which is to apply a general style and then reset that style for divs inside the class. That may or may not suit your needs, if it doesn't then unfortunately JavaScript is the only other option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the `#` *(id) selector*:

```css
#test div  { /* all div's inside the #test */
  background: #00f;
}

#testAgain div { /* all div's inside the #testAgain */
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">  
  <div>
    Some Content
  </div>
  <div>
    Some Content
    <div id="testAgain">
      <div>Some Content again</div>...<div>Test Content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    Some Content
    <div>
      Some Content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    Some Content
    <div>Some Content
      <div>Some Content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -4):

`div.test > div`

This selects all the direct descendants of div class test.

Comment: This won't work if there's a div inside another div.

Comment: Excatly! There are actually dozens of nested Divs.. and the `testAgain` class is somewhat 6-7 levels down the main div(`test` div)

Comment: This fulfils neither of OP's requirements? It won't select nested divs and it won't exclude divs that are direct children of #test with a class of .testAgain (assuming .testAgain can appear anywhere in the structure).